Questioning the Mark Scheme: Logical Equivalence in a Vampire-Werewolf Puzzle
This is not a homework question (I'm a maths tutor, not a student)
I recently attempted an exam question from the University of Oxford Mathematics Admissions Test (2015):

However, I believe there might be an error in the mark scheme for part (ii). Here's what the mark scheme states:

I disagree with the assertion that Cesare must be a vampire. If Cesare is a werewolf and Dita is a vampire, there is no contradiction, as all we can deduce is that Dita does not say, "Elith is a vampire." In fact, Dita might not say anything at all. I believe the mark scheme incorrectly treats the statement "Dita says 'Elith is a vampire'" as logically equivalent to "Dita is a vampire." While the former implies that Dita is a vampire, the converse does not necessarily hold.
Of course, I may be mistaken, which is why I’m seeking your feedback and insights. If I’m wrong, I would greatly appreciate an explanation.

You are correct: while only vampires can call somebody vampire, it's not necessary that every vampire calls everyone in the world a vampire, so in scenario "Dita is vampire, Elith is vampire" we don't know if Cesare's statement was true or false.

This book is weird. The second paragraph seems to agree with you but the fourth doesn't.  "I believe the mark scheme incorrectly treats the statement "Dita says 'Elith is a vampire'" as logically equivalent to "Dita is a vampire.""  IMO the statements are logically equivalent but if a person is lying and saying a statement that is equivalent to another lie, we can't claim the lying is actually saying the other statement.

Consider this.  Every time anyone says someone is a vampire they always hiccup. So if Cesare says "Dita is a vampire" he would hiccup. But if Cesare says "Dita says 'Elith is a vampire'" he didn't hiccup. Now the statement "Dita says 'Elith is a vampire'" is completely equivalent to "Dita is a vampire".  But it's not the same statement so Cesare needn't hiccup. Also I can easily imagine this conversation: C:D says 'E is V'.  Interviewer: Hmm, that satement implies D must be a Vampire.  Are you claiming D is a vampire.  C: No. (Utterly consistent)

@fleablood While I agree with your main point (Amy says, "3=3" doesn't imply Amy says, "5=5"), I am with the OP that this exam question's premises do not entail that Dita says, "Elith is a vampire" is equivalent to Dita is a vampire. On the other hand, these two statements are equivalent to each other: Dita says, "Elith is a vampire" and Dita is a vampire and Dita says either "Elith is a vampire" or "Elith isn't a vampire".



6.(ii) Cesare says, "Dita says, 'Elith is a vampire.'"


Considering cases reveals that the given statement is consistent with precisely the (six) cases in which at least one of Cesare and Dita is a vampire. (And we can soundly conclude that Cesare and Dita are not both werewolves.)
In particular—contrary to the mark scheme—the given statement is consistent with the two cases (C,D,E) = (werewolf, vampire, ?) with Dita being stoicly silent (making Dita says that 'Elith is a vampire' a lie).
I also agree that the mark scheme has baselessly extrapolated Part I's true results

A says, "B is a vampire" $\implies$ A is a vampire
A says, "B is a werewolf" $\implies$ A is a werewolf

as the false statements

A says, "B is a vampire" $\iff$ A is a vampire
A says, "B is a werewolf" $\iff$ A is a werewolf.

